# Why can termination checker affect strict Prop in Agda?

Tags: agda, predicativity, prop

In https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3290316 section 4 (which I believe is a standard reference), the authors claimed that Voevodsky's propositional resizing rule justifies the consistency of an impredicative strict Prop. This is also how it is implemented in Coq. Then, in section 6.5, Agda said the termination checker assumes predicativity and hence it's problematic to be impredicative. I don't understand that. I don't see the relation between termination checking and predicativity.

So, how does that affect predicativity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I have found a [counterexample](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/3883#issuecomment-508416591) by Jesper Cockx:

```
data ⊥ : Prop where

data Bad : Prop where
  b : ((P : Prop) → P → P) → Bad

bad : Bad
bad = b (λ P p → p)

no-bad : Bad → ⊥
no-bad (b x) = no-bad (x Bad bad)

very-bad : ⊥
very-bad = no-bad bad
```

It looks like the recursion `no-bad (x _)` should be forbidden.

Comment: I love this counter-example! I wonder where it originated (I remember seeing a similar one long ago...)

Comment: @cody The example is in A Predicative Analysis of Structural Recursion by Abel and Altenkirch, which I think Agda's checker is based on. Just before, they cite Pattern Matching with Dependent Types by T. Coquand from 1992, so that might be the actual origin. I can't find a copy of the latter, though.

Comment: Thanks @DanDoel! Looks like the Coquand paper (https://wonks.github.io/type-theory-reading-group/papers/proc92-coquand.pdf) actually does contain the counter-example on Page 4.